# Flask-WTF: how to set a dynamic number of fields in the html file?

Tags: python, html, csv, flask, flask-wtforms

I have a Flask-WTF form with a number of simple fields (checkboxes). I got a piece of Python code that creates field variables according to a csv file which changes size. This means that every time somebody load the web form, the number of fields may be different.

Here's my Flask-WTF Python code:

```
from flask.ext.wtf import Form
import csv
from wtforms import TextField, RadioField, TextAreaField, SubmitField, validators, BooleanField

class ContactForm(Form):

    # Creation dynamic local variables, one for each field
    with open('/Fields.csv', 'rb') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        r = list(reader)

    for i in range(1,len(r)):
        locals()[''.join("field_"+str(i))] = BooleanField(str(r[i][0])+" "+str(r[i][1]))

    submit = SubmitField("Send")
```

If inelegant, this works: the code produces variables called field_1, field_2, field_3, ..., field_n (where n is the total number of entries in the csv file).

Now, this is -if I understand it well- how Flask-WTF works: I need to write an html file that will display these fields. Like such:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}  

    <form action="{{ url_for('home') }}" method=post>
      {{ form.hidden_tag() }}

       <h2>List of checkboxes dynamically built from local csv file</h2>

      #this needs to be dynamically set
      {{ form.field_1.label }}
      {{ form.field_1 }}

      {{ form.field_2.label }}
      {{ form.field_2 }}

      {{ form.field_3.label }}
      {{ form.field_3 }}

      ...

      {{ form.submit }}
    </form>

  {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

My problem is that, not knowing how many fields there are in my csv file, I can't prewrite the lines:

```
{{ form.field_1.label }}
{{ form.field_1 }}
```

Is there a way to pass the number of required fields from the Flask-WTF code to the html file, and then, somehow in the html file, make the corresponding number of fields?

Comment: Have you considered using a [`FieldList`](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/0.6/fields.html#wtforms.fields.FieldList)?

Comment: No I haven't, I'll see how this would work, thanks!

Comment: Why not read the csv file outside of the class? r would then be a variable that you could import from your forms file. You are likely already doing imports for your forms in your views file. So you would add something like `from forms import ContactForm, r`. r would then be accessible in your views, which could then be passed into the jinja template.